# Bootstrap change carousel height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/gh4Lur4b/8/

It's a full width bootstrap carousel.

I'd like to change the height and still keep it full width.

Is the height determined by the image height?

How can I change the height of the carousel and keep it 100% width?

```
.carousel-inner{
    // height: 300px;
}

.item, img{
    height: 100% !important;
    width:  100% !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: You made a typo in the question

Comment: The best way to decrease size is changing the images height

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following should work

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh4Lur4b/18/) for reference.

Comment: This doesn't change the image size. The carousel changes size but not the image. I think I was hoping for something like `background-size:cover;` so the image stretches http://jsfiddle.net/gh4Lur4b/17/

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Sorry that wasn't clear from your original question. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: But now the image is squashed when the window is made smaller. In your jsfiddle when the window is made bigger the image is not stretched but expands. I need a similar effect when the window is made smaller.

Comment: Do you know these images before-hand? In other words, can you access them within your CSS?

Comment: Also, this method seems to not be working if you use 50% as the height. Anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You may also want to add

```
object-fit: cover;
```

To preserve the aspect ration for different window sizes

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

For **Bootstrap 4** and above replace `.item` with `.carousel-item`

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Speaking only for Bootstrap 4 (I haven't looked at the older ones), surely you mean `.carousel .carousel-item { height: .....` , not `.carousel .item ` ?

Comment: excellent answer for bootstrap 4 and above replace `.item` with `.carousel-item` as the comment above says.

Answer (score 10):

From **Bootstrap 4**

```
.carousel-item{
    height: 200px;
} 
.carousel-item img{
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
like Answers above, if you do bootstrap 4 just add few line of css to .carousel , carousel-inner ,carousel-item and img as follows

.carousel .carousel-inner{
height:500px
}
.carousel-inner .carousel-item img{
min-height:200px;
//prevent it from stretch in screen size < than 768px
object-fit:cover
}

@media(max-width:768px){
.carousel .carousel-inner{
//prevent it from adding a white space between carousel and container elements
height:auto
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if someone comes here looking exactly for what the headline points to, this will help (remember it's OK to use jQuery in Bootstrap v4):

```js
$.fn.normalizeHeight = function () {
    $(this).css("height", Math.max.apply(null, $(this).children().map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    })) + "px");

    return this;
};
```

It would simply be called with:

```
$("#slider .carousel-inner").normalizeHeight();

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  $("#slider .carousel-inner").normalizeHeight();
});
```

It is ES5 compliant + would work in other needed equal child height.

Answer (score -2):

For Bootstrap 4

In the same line as image
add `height: 300px;`

```
<img src="..." style="height: 300px;" class="d-block w-100" alt="image">
```

Answer (score -2):

Try following it should work:

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
    max-height:550px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    object-fit:cover;
    max-height:550px;
}
```