# How to insert a Bootstrap Carousel using Software Landing Page template?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. So far, I was able to customize the template I based my webpage on to what I want, but I am currently having trouble adding a carousel to the fourth page. I tried to google around for working codes using a carousel away from the top of the page, but I didn't find any except one having a separate page for it. It is not possible using Bootstrap on the same webpage? Here is the link to the web template I am struggling with: [Software Landing Page](http://demo.themewagon.com/preview/boxer-software-landing-page-free-html5-template)

Comment: You can use a carousel anywhere on your page if bootstrap.js is included, which it is.

Comment: Then it must be the template I am using. It is preventing me to add a properly formatted carousel. The template used divides each page using section tag followed by a few inner div tags. Adding the code for the carousel to a section will cause its height to shrink to a height much less than half of the improper carousel can be seen.

Comment: Put the code inside of the `<div class="row"></div>` and set a height on the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, lameemon. That was what I needed. I had the right div tags, but I just need to set a height for the carousel or the section is cut down in height.

I achieved that from the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589911/bootstrap-change-carousel-height):

```
<style>
.carousel .item {
  height: 400px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
</style>
```