# How to make my carousel fill only 60% of screen size so the rest can be used by panels directly below it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How could I make the following carousel fill only 60% of screen size (without scrolling) so the remaining 40% can be used by panels directly below it. Images would have to shrink along with carousel depending on desktop screen-size to fill only 60%.

Please note:
I have looked at the post [Bootstrap change carousel height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589911/bootstrap-change-carousel-height), and tried changing

```
.carousel-inner{
   height: 60%px;
}

.item, img{
    height: 100% !important;
    width:  100% !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but without success.

The code for my current layout is:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <title>Layout Sample</title>
  </head>

  <body class="body-cust text-white">

  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="images/logo.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""> 
    </a> <!-- Navigation Logo Goes here -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forum</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline"> <!-- MUST ADD form-inline class here-->
      <!-- input fields -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label style="margin-right: 10px">E-Mail</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
      </div>
      <span style="width: 15px"></span>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label style="margin-right: 10px">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <span style="width: 10px"></span>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-pink my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide caroussel-cust" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ed895556f%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ed895556f%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22284.5%22%20y%3D%22220.1%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ed8955574%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ed8955574%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22245.5%22%20y%3D%22220.1%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <!-- 3rd Caroussel Image -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_15ed895557a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_15ed895557a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22275.5%22%20y%3D%22220.1%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style=" background-color: green; height: 50px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style=" background-color: red; height: 50px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style=" background-color: yellow; height: 50px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the height of the carousel and .item using "viewport height":

```
.carousel-inner{
   height: 60vh;
}

.item, img{
    height: 60vh !important;
    width:  60vh !important;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```