# Carousel Height Problem, The default Carousel height is too large

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am trying to shorten the height to `500px` from `1000px`. Since this is my first time including `bootstrap` I have difficulty understanding which css class affects the carousel. If you can give me tips or a guide it would be much appreciated

Code

Comment: You can check bootstrap documentation as well.

Comment: Or you can create a new class and define the height by yourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap change carousel height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589911/bootstrap-change-carousel-height)

Comment: You should check for your problem before posting a question and then post what you tried and didn't work. This particular question has been asked and answered many times. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is set to a max-width of 500px.

Here it is in a [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/GRgJzmq), too.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placeimg.com/1920/1080/1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placeimg.com/1920/1080/2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placeimg.com/1920/1080/3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```